# UI testing Xcode 7, How to get access to element in collectionview

Tags: ios, user-interface, testing, xcode7, ui-testing

I have an collectionview with invested ellements inside. The objects coming as images. So the problem is taping on these elements. I can`t pick elements from this window, and Accessibility Inspector showing my whole window with elements as button with missing accessibility values.

[Image of Accessibility Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJbEZ.png)

So, if I am using just Record button, then I am getting this code, but it doesn`t work to play. I still have no lables and indexes.

> XCUIApplication().childrenMatchingType(.Window).elementBoundByIndex(0).childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Button).element.tap()

Does anyone know, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Ok, some additional detail. There is collectionview which covered all over by button, so i cant pick elements under it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access control in following manner (better to debug and check value of each element in progressive manner using `po`)

```
[XCUIApplication.buttons elementBoundbyIndex:0]
```

Or
`[[[XCUIApplication.windows elementBoundbyIndex:0] buttons] elementBoundbyIndex:0]` ... so on.